# VBA to C#: Dim x

Tags: c#, vba

I'm porting some VBA code into C#, and at the beginning of one of the functions to port is the line:

```
 Dim sCA;
```

Is there any way of finding out what I should store this as in C#? I need to pull a string out of it, but the methods from the library I'm using returns a number, which then confuses the compiler when I try to use IndexOf(). When I check the parameters list for the function used to set it, I see this:

```
ReadValue([DataPoint As String], [intErrorMode As Integer = 0])
```

Seeing as there is no `ReadValue()` in C#, I'm a little stuck at the moment, is anything you can throw at me will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Apologies for the mess that went on down there, here's the full function:

```
Sub CheckForPin(sSTB As String, sPIN As String, iSetTopBoxID As Integer)
Dim sCA_PopUp

sCA_PopUp = ReadValue("Fix32." & SCADA_NAME & "." & sSTB & CStr(iSetTopBoxID) & "_POPUP_CA" & ".F_CV", 1)
If InStr(1, UCase(sCA_PopUp), "PIN PROTECTED") <> 0 Then
    WriteValue sPIN, "Fix32." & SCADA_NAME & "." & sSTB & CStr(iSetTopBoxID) & "_MULTIPLE_CMD" & ".A_CV", 1
End If

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Could you post a bit more of the original VBA code to help us get some context?

Comment: Perhaps edit your question with the complete code. Don't put it in comments

Comment: Have you tried simply using `var`?

If the compiler still complains, I'd try `object`, and if you get no luck there then `dynamic`, should certainly solve the issue.

Comment: It seems to like the dynamic modifier, the only problem I have now is that the VB Editor wont let me into the ReadValue method to see fully what it does. I tried var and object earlier, but to no avail. Thanks for the suggestion, Joshua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the original programmers prefixed all variables with a type indicator (in this case, the "s"), it is safe to deduce that it is indeed a string.  Also, I'm not sure if Dim sCA_PopUp and Dim sCA are referring to the same variable and you just didn't catch this, but if so, from the heavy concatenation going on, there is further evidence that it should be interpreted as a string.   When you convert this to C#, use StringBuilder instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ReadValue is returning a string; so the C# is

```
void CheckForPin(...)
{
   string sCA_PopUp = ReadValue(...)
   if (sCA_PopUp.ToUpper().Contains("PIN PROTECTED"))
   {
      WriteValue(...)
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW, I agree with @Joshua, using `var` is a nice short-cut, but you should know the types you are playing with.